# lightning datatable populate on paste from clipboard

Tags: lightning, lightning-events, lightning-datatable

Is it currently possible access the clipboard conents from the onpaste event for the lightning datatable? If so how? If not then is there a work around?

I want to copy an paste from Excel and populate the lightning datatable from the contents.

```
    <lightning:datatable aura:id="definitions"
                         data="{! v.scenario_definition }"
                         columns="{! v.scenario_definition_columns}"
                         keyField="id"
                         onpaste="{!c.paste}" 
                         >

 paste: function(component, event, helper) {                       
        let paste_ok = document.queryCommandSupported("paste");
        console.log('Is paste ok: ' + paste_ok);
    }
```

I want the controller to parse the data on the clipboard then fill the data table. Should be simple.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the code you've tried so far? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There is no such `onpaste` event on `lightning:datatable`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/specification) document, the `onpaste` event is not supported for the datatable.

Besides, the datatable object is designed more like a read/edit of existing rows than an actual spreadsheet.

You may want to try capturing the paste at the component level and then adding those rows yourself to the array (`v.scenario_definition`) that powers the datatable.

Comment: It isn't documented. onpaste="{!c.paste}" does work with lightning:datatable. An event does fire when you do Ctrl+v and you can handle it. However you don't have access to the clipboard.

Comment: @ploc Anything undocumented thing could still work, BUT you should avoid using such things as it could stop working at a point and that you will not get any support around such thing from Salesforce